# Smooth scroll not allowing me to scroll down page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I added in the github plugin for the smooth scroll effect.

github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll

I added in the call outs for the effect:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://simov.github.io/simplr-smoothscroll/lib/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

Then I added this code for the effect:

```
$(function () { $.srSmoothscroll() });
```

After I did this, my page no longer scrolls down. It only scrolls up. Why is this not functioning correctly?

The site I added this on is this page from the site:

http://realtorcatch.com/test_index

I am wanting it to model after:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51054.html

On githubs site, it says the usage is this:

```
$(function () {
 $.srSmoothscroll({
    // defaults
    step: 55,
    speed: 400,
    ease: 'swing',
    target: $('body'),
    container: $(window)
  })
})
```

But I was told just adding in the code I added would work. This:

```
$(function () { $.srSmoothscroll() });
```

Does anyone have any ideas to why this is not scrolling down?